# How do I get this program to allow decimals to be entered?

Tags: c#, decimal

I have this question that I have to do for an assignment for school. I am having troubles making it work with decimals. If someone could help me get the program to accept decimals. It will output a decimal but it won't let me input one.

```
using System;

    public class Bank_Account
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            char input, C, D, P, Q;
            double balance;

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter C for Cheque, D for Deposit, P for Print or Q to quit");
            input = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
            do
            {
                switch (input)
                {
                    case 'D':
                        Deposit(ref balance);
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                        Print(balance);
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        Cheque(ref balance);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid choice", input);
                        break;
                }
            } while (input != 'Q');

        }

        public static void Deposit(ref double balance)
        {
            double deposit;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount you want to deposit: ");
            deposit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (deposit > 1000)
            {
                deposit = deposit*1.02;
            }
            else
            {
                deposit = deposit;
            }

            balance = +deposit;
        }


        public static void Cheque(ref double balance)
        {
            var tempBalance = balance;
            double deduction;
            const double fee = 1;


            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of the cheque: ");
                deduction = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            } while (deduction < 0);


            tempBalance = balance - deduction - fee;
            if (tempBalance < 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Not enough money in the account");
            }
            else
            {
                balance = tempBalance;
            }
        }


        public static void Print(double balance)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your current balance is {0.00}", balance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you are converting the input to an integer. Integers don't have decimals.

Comment: Maybe you want to use `Convert.ToDouble ` for the input instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
deposit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

to:

```
deposit = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

since you're not reading an int, but a double. Using `TryParse` like suggested in another answer would be even better. Also, maybe you should be using [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28VS.80%29.aspx) and not double if you need exactness, but double if accuracy is less of a concern.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting to Int, change like this,

```
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the amount of the cheque: ");
            deduction = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
double deposit;
double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out deposit);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deposit = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```